# Change nameddest default name

Tags: hyperref, formatting, pdf, lyx

Adobe defines parameters that allow you to open a PDF document with a command or URL that specifies exactly what to display (a named destination or specific page), and how to display it (using such characteristics as a specific view, scrollbars, bookmarks, annotations, or highlighting).

My question is:

Is there a way to change the pdf nameddest generated by a LyX document? The default parameters are Chapter.1, Chapter.2, Chapter.3... Section.1.1, Section.1.2, Section.3.2...

for example, in the browser, to open a pdf document (generated by lyx or tex) on a determinated spot:

```
file:///C:/teste1.pdf#nameddest=chapter.4
file:///C:/teste1.pdf#nameddest=section.2.4
```

I need to change these default names, the document is always being updated so references to chapters and sections have a high turnover.

Maybe a renew command, like `\renewcommand{\section}{}`?

Comment: nobody knows? :(

Comment: You could try asking in the *lyx-users* mailing list, that can be found at http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Answer (score 17):

The links and destinations are added by package hyperref. Because destinations need
different names, the names are composed by the counter name and the counter value.

But having a symbolic destination name is indeed a useful feature. Therefore I have
implemented such a feature in hyperref 2012/07/28 v6.82u. It is enabled by package
option `destlabel`. Later it cannot be enabled using `\hypersetup`.

With option `destlabel` the name of the first `\label` after an anchor setting
is used to set the destination name that is used in the next LaTeX run.

For a better understanding of the destination name stuff in hyperref I have written
a section to the hyperref manual that I here quote for convenience.

> **Options for destination names**
>
> Destinations names (also anchor, target or link names) are internal
>   names that identify a position on a page in the document. They
>   are used in link targets for inner document links or the bookmarks,
>   for example.
>
> Usually anchor are set, if `\refstepcounter` is called.
>   Thus there is a counter name and value. Both are used to
>   construct the destination name. By default the counter value
>   follows the counter name separated by a dot. Example for
>   the fourth chapter:
>
> ```
> chapter.4
> ```
>
> This scheme is used by:
>
> - `\autoref` displays the description label for the
>     reference depending on the counter name.
> - `\hyperpage` is used by the index to get
>     page links. Page anchor setting (`pageanchor`) must not
>     be turned off.
>
> It is very important that the destination names are unique,
>   because two destinations must not share the same name.
>   The counter value `\the<counter>` is not always unique
>   for the counter. For example, table and figures can be numbered
>   inside the chapter without having the chapter number in their
>   number. Therefore hyperref has introduced `\theH<counter>`
>   that allows a unique counter value without messing up with
>   the appearance of the counter number. For example, the number
>   of the second table in the third chapter might be printed
>   as `2`, the result of `\thetable`. But the
>   destination name `table.2.4` is unique because it
>   has used `\theHtable` that gives `2.4` in this case.
>
> Often the user do not need to set `\theH<counter>`. Defaults
>   for standard cases (chapter, \dots) are provided. And after hyperref
>   is loaded, new counters with parent counters also define
>   `\theH<counter>` automatically, if `\newcounter`, `\@addtoreset`
>   or `\numberwithin` of package amsmath are used.
>
> Usually problems with duplicate destination names can be solved
>   by an appropriate definition of `\theH<counter>`. If option
>   `hypertexnames` is disabled, then a unique artificial
>   number is used instead of the counter value. In case of page
>   anchors the absolute page anchor is used. With option `plainpages`
>   the page anchors use the arabic form. In both latter cases `\hyperpage`
>   for index links is affected and might not work properly.
>
> If an unnumbered entity gets an anchor (starred forms of
>   chapters, sections, …) or `\phantomsection` is used,
>   then the dummy counter name `section*` and an artificial
>   unique number is used.
>
> If the final PDF file is going to be merged with another file, than
>   the destination names might clash, because both documents might
>   contain `chapter.1` or `page.1`. Also hyperref
>   sets anchor with name `Doc-Start` at the begin of the document.
>   This can be resolved by redefining `\HyperDestNameFilter`.
>   Package hyperref calls this macro each time, it uses a destination name.
>   The macro must be expandable and expects the destination name
>   as only argument. As example, the macro is redefined to add
>   a prefix to all destination names:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\jobname-#1}
> ```
>
> In document `docA` the destination name `chapter.2`
>   becomes `docA-chapter.2`.
>
> Destination names can also be used from the outside in URIs(, if the
>   driver has not removed or changed them), for example:
>
> ```
> http://somewhere/path/file.pdf#nameddest=chapter.4
> ```
>
> However using a number seems unhappy. If another chapter is added
>   before, the number changes. But it is very difficult to pass
>   a new name for the destination to the anchor setting process that
>   is usually deep hidden in the internals. The first name of
>   `label` after the anchor setting seems a good approximation:
>
> ```
> \section{Introduction}
> \label{intro}
> ```
>
> Option `destlabel` checks for each `\label`, if there is
>   a new destination name active and replaces the destination
>   name by the label name. Because the destination name is already in use
>   because of the anchor setting, the new name is recorded in the `.aux`
>   file and used in the subsequent LaTeX run. The renaming is done by
>   a redefinition of `\HyperDestNameFilter`. That leaves the old
>   destination names intact (e.g., they are needed for `\autoref`).
>   This redefinition is also available as `\HyperDestLabelReplace`,
>   thus that an own redefinition can use it.
>   The following example also adds a prefix for *all* destination names:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{%
>   \jobname-\HyperDestLabelReplace{#1}%
> }
> ```
>
> The other case that only files prefixed that do not have a corresponding
>   `\label` is more complicate, because `\HyperDestLabelReplace` needs
>   the unmodified destination name as argument. This is solved by an
>   expandable string test (`\pdfstrcmp` of pdfTeX
>   or `\strcmp` of XeTeX, package pdftexcmds also supports LuaTeX):
>
> ```
> \usepackage{pdftexcmds}
> \makeatletter
> \renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{%
>   \ifcase\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\HyperDestLabelReplace{#1}} %
>     \jobname-#1%
>   \else
>     \HyperDestLabelReplace{#1}%
>   \fi
> }
> \makeatother
> ```
>
> With option `destlabel` destinations can also named manually,
>   if the destination is not yet renamed:
>
> ```
> \HyperDestRename{<destination>}{<newname>}
> ```
>
> Hint: Anchors can also be named and set by `\hypertarget`.