# Change Named Destinations using destlabel option of hyperref

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, lyx, pdf

PDF Named-Destinations are made by Hyperref.
[This shows how to change them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30562/change-nameddest-default-name) by using hyperref option destlabel=true, then redefining using /label.
Unfortunately, it does not seem to work.

**answer:---Its Lyx--- (but not a solution)**

(should have looked in the latex, my bad). 
The **document->settings->pdf properties->options** field on PDF Preferences is put into `\hypersetup{ destlabel=true}`, not the `\usepackage[destlabel=true]{hyperref}`. As Heiko originally noted, that doesn't work.

Preamble from Lyx:

```
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
   bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
   breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ destlabel=true}
```

When I directly `\usepackage[destlabel=true]{hyperref}` in the preamble it works.

Unfortunately other packages that lyx loads, are dependent on being loaded *after* Hyperref, so usepackage hyperref, can't be moved to the preamble.

So what is needed is for the Lyx Preamble to be:

```
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
   bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
   breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false,
   destlabel=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{}
```

Unfortunately that is a lyx UI change.

Is there any other way to make the destlabel=true work in hypersetup, or elsewhere?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document (and I don't mean the LyX file!)

Comment: RenamedIt is being added to the PDF list of anchors, but it is not being assigned to the same location as section.3 (or section.1 in my case).

Comment: What exactly would you like the preamble to look like in LyX? If you could specify the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line and tell LyX not to add it, would that work for you? What exactly would you like the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line to look line?

Comment: @scottkosty I have edited the question above, to show what the lyx generated preamble should look like. It seems that hyperref requires 2 option lines to be used fully: "_additional hyperref options_" (new) and "_additional hypersetup options_" (the existing editbox)

Comment: @HenryCrun regarding "Unfortunately other packages that [LyX] loads, are dependent on being loaded after hyperref", can you please upload a minimal example showing the particular problem that happens for you? It is not that i don't believe you (in fact I know this statement is correct), but the solution depends on the particular conflict you are facing.

Comment: @HenryCrun what happens if you add 'destlabel=true' to the document class options? Does hyperref then see and use that option when loading the package? Again, a minimal .lyx example would be useful. Please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2):

There is an option `destlabel`, which uses the name of the first `\label` after the anchor creation to name the anchor:

```
\ifx\pdfobjcompresslevel\undefined\else\pdfobjcompresslevel=0 \fi % Debug

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[destlabel=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\end{document}
```

The first line is just for pdfLaTeX to make it easier to read the PDF file
via a text viewer (or editor) to find the destination names in the PDF file
(in short, `/Catalog`→`/Names`→`/Dests`). The `/Dests` object references object 21 in the generated PDF file:

```pdf
21 0 obj
<<
/Names [(Doc-Start) 10 0 R (intro) 2 0 R (page.1) 9 0 R]
/Limits [(Doc-Start) (page.1)]
>>
endobj
```

There are three names: `Doc-Start` is added by `hyperref` at the begin
of the document. `page.1` is the automatically created page label (controlled by option `pageanchor`). The destination for `\section{Introduction}` is `intro`, named by `\label{intro}`.

Comment: Interestingly,  it takes two runs.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Of course. At the time of `\section` with the anchor setting it is not yet known that there will be a `\label` command.  LaTeX's `\label` feature needs two runs anyway, thus this is not a drawback.

Comment: Actually, the reason is that the aux file contains \hyper@newdestlabel{oldname}{newname} which does all the work.

Comment: @heiko I now think that LyX is misusing Hypersetup in the preamble (immediately after /usepackage hyperref ). Could you have a look at my comment here: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10319#comment:7 and comment on whether I am correct to think this?

Comment: @HenryCrun Yes, `destlabel` should go to the options of `usepackage`, because `destlabel` is used at package loading time. Later uses of `destlabel` should give a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need `destlabel=true` in the preamble, but you cannot use a `\label` AND `\HyperDestRename`, not even if you use the label name instead of `\@currentHref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[destlabel=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\hyperdest#1{\global\let#1=\@currentHref}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]% skip first page

\section{Introduction}
\hyperdest{\myname}
\HyperDestRename{\myname}{ExternalName}

\lipsum[6-10]

\section{Development}% new \@currentHref

\hyperlink{\myname}{test}\par\noindent
\hyperlink{ExternalName}{same target}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry John, I don't quite see what you are doing.

Comment: When I try this I get a visible hyperlink labelled "test", which jumps to "intro" within the pdf. It does not result in a named-destination (external anchor for hyperlinks from outside the pdf) however. What I think I want to do is make a hypertarget and label with the text of the section (but spaces changed to underscores).

Comment: I am not understanding why the _hyperdest_ macro. Why does '\HyperDestRename{\@currentHref}{ExternalName}' not work, when '\HyperDestRename{\myname}{ExternalName}' does work?  [nor does '{@currentHref}' , '{currentHref}' , '{\currentHref}'

Comment: The @ symbol is used in sty files to create macro names that users will not accidentally redefine, or use.  The \makeatletter ... \makeatother overcomes this restriction.  \csname @currentHref\endcsname will also work.