# How to use destlabel option together with default names?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, multiple-files

Suppose I have the following in document A:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[destlabel]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\newpage
\section{Link Section}\label{mylabel}
\end{document}
```

and the following in document B:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Link 1: Please see \href{docA.pdf#mylabel}{this section}.

Link 2: Please see \hyperref{docA.pdf}{section}{2}{this section}.
\end{document}
```

Link 1 works when I have the `destlabel` option set and link 2 works when I don't set this option. How can I make both links work?

The reason that I want both of these methods to work simultaneously is that I do *not* want to use absolute references myself (because of sections that get inserted or deleted later on), but I do want to allow people from the outside to link to (sections in) my PDF's without them having to know the new destination names that were replaced by the `destlabel` option. Is this possible?

The documentation of `hyperref` did not clarify it. In fact, I thought the following bit of text in the documentation implied that both *should* work simultaneously:

> The renaming is done by a redefinition of `\HyperDestNameFilter`. That leaves the old destination names intact.

Comment: Don't show only a few snippets, make complete test documents.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321671/134641

Comment: I added an MWE to my question instead of the snippets. I did read related articles on my problem, but that's just what they are: related, not duplicates. Unfortunately, they didn't help much.